# Cross Compiling PyZMQ

Tags: python, linux, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross compile PyZMQ for a target. Initially I had cross compiled PyZMQ with libzmq bundled and then loaded onto the target which had worked fine. However if i want to cross compile libzmq previously and then try to cross compile PyZMQ linking it to the libzmq, will it be pointing to the libzmq.so onto the target also?

We can do a python setup.py configure --zmq=/path for libzmq/ which works fine for the host compile and installation. But if we need to cross compile do we need to set any extra variables such as LDFLAGS which i am not sure how to use in this case.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: paste your error message along with how you compiling ?

Comment: Well actually i have not tried to cross compile with ZeroMQ of the SDK. This is just a theoretical question. I have wrote a recipe in Bitbake.